# Downloading Entire Albums from ICloud.com Ends Up with Images with .resOriginalRes file exention

Tags: icloud, photos

I need to download around 10,000 photos from my iCloud library.  I NEED to keep the album structure because reorganizing all these photos would take forever!

I downloaded about 50 albums with no problem, I got a zip folder that I extracted all the photos from.  But now a lot of the zips are being downloaded with these odds files (presumably the image files with weird names and a .resOriginalRes file extension.

I can not open or do anything with these .resOriginalRes files and the actual .jpg are not in the zip.  Below is an image of what I'm talking about...

[image]

Any ideas or help?

**EDIT: If someone knows a better way to download my library and keep the album structure please let me know!**

Comment: Once they are downloaded what are you going to do with them. Don't they just appear in iPhot anyway?

Comment: I'm downloading the images from iCloud, then uploading them into a website to put into an online gallery.  Obviously, jpg, png, etc are fine but these .resOriginalRes files are useless.

Comment: Use Photos app - select the photos and then use Export from the File menu

Comment: I'm using Photos on iCloud.com to download each album to my PC.   I don't see a File menu.

Comment: Ah you tagged with Photos.app which as the tag information said when you chose it "Apple's photo manager and editor. This tag may refer to the iOS app, present since iOS 1.0; the OS X app" So please actuallyu tell us the correct setup in your question

Comment: Sorry I removed the tag.  I'm using a windows PC to download the images from iCloud.com.  I then take the downloaded zip and un-zip.  Typically that gives me the photos I want (JPGs & PNGs).  But in some cases I end up with files like the image in the question and no actual images.

Comment: I got them downloaded as a zip of .heic files I hit the download icon at the top right

Comment: .heic ?  Where do you set that?

Comment: It is what the web iclod.com downloads as. I have not set anything. Albeit I am using Firefox on macOS - so not a Safari related thing

Comment: Also that was in Photos on the iCloud page not iCloud drive

Comment: How large are these files?

Comment: The files vary in size, from a couple MB to a GIG.